# Как в bachInsert сопоставить данные с полями?

Tags: yii2

```
public static  $columnsInsert =
    [
        'id',
        'customer_id',
        'summary',
        'description',
        'color',
        'favourite',
        'update_at',
        'create_at',
        'personEmail'
    ];


$sql = $db->queryBuilder->batchInsert(self::$table, self::$columnsInsert, $data);
```

С клиента приходят массивы строк с такими же ключами в строке. Но почему то данные не сопоставляются с полями в запросе. Неужели надо подбирать порядок под данные с клиента.